# Difference between Displacement from Equilibrum and Amplitude of SHM

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, terminology, equilibrium, displacement

I'm currently studying Simple Harmonic Motion. What is the difference between the amplitude of the simple harmonic motion, and its displacement from equilibrium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum displacement of a particle from its mean position in SHM is defined as the *amplitude* of the SHM, whereas displacement is just the shift or movement of the particle from its equilibrium position.

The displacement can take any value less than or equal to the amplitude of the SHM.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Amplitude of a particle performing SHM is the maximum displacement from the equilibrium position it *can achieve* during its motion while displacement from mean/equilibrium position suggests its set off from the equilibrium position *at that instant* , for example,
If a particle if performing SHM on x-axis , about the mean position x = 2 and maximum co-ordinate along +ve x-axis being x = 5 then its amplitude is 3 units
but at any time t its co-ordinate are x = 0 , then its displacement from mean position will be 2 units while amplitude remains the same 3 units .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!